# method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception

{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/convocation","root","");



    *String id_convo= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input ConvoID"));*
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Insert Student ConvoID");

    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from stud_details where id='"+id_convo+"' ");

    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

    while(result.next())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,result.getString(1) + " "+ result.getString(2));
    }
}
}
```

Basically this is my code. I would like user to enter convo id(eg:01, 02) and it come out with the details from the database id 01 or 02.
However, I dont know why there is an error where Integer is not applicable for the arguments (void). 
and i dont know why. I tried to remove the String[]args but nothing works.
what should i do? thanks

Comment: Read the error message. You're passing a void type (showMessageDialog returns void) when you should be passing a string. Additionally, I assume you're trying to parse a string, but then you're just assigning it back to a string. Either parse an actual integer string and assign it to an integer or just leave it as a string.

Comment: Check the [JavaDoc for JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: This is one of those questions where it would take you less time to read the messages IDE is giving you, than it took you to post the question on SO

Answer (score 2):

The statement `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Input ConvoID")` does not return a `String`. What returns a `String` is the method that is called right after that statement: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. So the code should be as follows:

```
int id_convo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Insert Student ConvoID"));
```

Note that `id_convo` should be of type `int` not `String`.